# Solving a trigonometric equation for all $x$ using constant coefficients

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, replacement, expression-manipulation, trigonometry

I want to find the coefficients $a$, $b$, $c$, etc. that make an equation like $a+bx=x$ true for all $x$, but for trigonometric functions of $x$. For example

```
SolveAlways[a + b x == x, x]
```

returns

```
{{a -> 0, b -> 1}}
```

On the other hand,

```
SolveAlways[Sin[x] == Sin[a x], x]
```

returns

```
SolveAlways::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by SolveAlways, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
{{Sin[x] -> Sin[a x]}, {}}
```

Any tips on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Reduce[Sin[x] == Sin[a x], x]` should give you the results and conditions for the results to hold true.

The result may seem complex, however it is complete and correct. If you take some time to look into the result, it may appear simple and understandable. Further, you can choose the parts of the solution depending on your value of $a$.